# iOS: Drag Effect not working well

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have implemented the drag effect on an image but during my test I see that the image is moving only on the click mouse event.

I cannot move my image with the mouse on my screen through the drag event. But when I click on a side of my screen the image take the place where I have clicked.

I followed many topics on youtube but finally, I haven't the same behavior.

This my code:

ScreenView1.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

ScreenView1.m

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    image.center = location;
    [self ifCollision];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to drag an image view, you will be *so* much happier using a UIPanGestureRecognizer. It makes this sort of thing trivial. Using `touchesBegan` is so iOS 4!

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* p =
    [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(dragging:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:p];

// ...

- (void) dragging: (UIPanGestureRecognizer*) p {
    UIView* vv = p.view;
    if (p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
            p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint delta = [p translationInView: vv.superview];
        CGPoint c = vv.center;
        c.x += delta.x; c.y += delta.y;
        vv.center = c;
        [p setTranslation: CGPointZero inView: vv.superview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt. But I am not so advanced in this environment, just since few days. May you give me more explanation. I guess I have to include the component UIPanGestureRecognizer on my View. I have associated a Custom Class. But after that, I don't really know where could I put your code.

Comment: I've written you an entire book to help you! The part you want starts here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_gesture_recognizers

Comment: I have used : "if(CGRectIntersectsRect(menu1Drag.frame, menu2Drag.frame))" to manage the collision object. Is it incompatible with the PanGesture?

Comment: @SAPDEV Once you've got the basic drag working, ask a whole new question about the "collision"!

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing the right thing in the `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, which is why the drag won't work. Here's a little code that works:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    [image setCenter:location];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: CATransaction need a specific include? Because I have an error at this 3 lines ...

Comment: You'll have to import QuartzCore I think.

Answer (score 0):

For the others, I have implemented my issue in that way:

```
- (IBAction)catchPanEvent:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

thank you again Matt!